# How is font-size not working here?

Tags: html, css, layout, font-size

Following advice in [The 6 Most Important CSS Techniques You Need To Know](http://trevordavis.net/blog/tutorial/the-6-most-important-css-techniques-you-need-to-know/), I set my body's `font-size` to `62.5%`, the `container` div's `font-size` to 1.4 em (slight variation from the article). `p.tags` and `p.published`'s `font-size` is set to 1em.

However, this doesn't work for me. Both the normal text and text in `p.tags` and `p.published` comes out to be the same size (16.8px as computed by Firebug). Can you explain why my code isn't working? I am testing in Firefox 3.6.3. The [sample page](http://trevordavis.net/play/important-css-techniques/base-font-size/) shown by the author works just fine in the very same browser.

I've reproduced the entire page below—apologies for the length of it, but I thought it better to not leave out anything.

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Title</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                        body {
                                font-family: Georgia, "Century Schoolbook", "Times New Roman", Serif;
                                font-size: 62.5%;
                                background-color: #2B3856; /* Dark slate blue */
                        }
                        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
                                font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Tahoma, "Sans Serif";
                                color: #2B3856;
                                margin-top: 2px;
                        }
                        h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
                                text-decoration: none;
                                color: #2B3856;
                        }
                        h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover, h5 a:hover, h6 a:hover {
                                text-decoration: underline;
                        }
                        div#container {
                                width: 800px;
                                font-size: 1.4em;
                                margin: 5px auto;
                                background-color: #E3E4FA; /* Lavender */
                        }
                        #sidebar {
                                width: 200px;
                                float: right;
                                margin: 0px;
                                padding: 0px;
                        }
                        #sidebar div {
                                padding: 0 5px 5px;
                        }
                        #sidebar div.shadowbox { margin-right: 5px; }
                        #content {
                                width: 600px;
                                float: left;
                                margin: 0px;
                                padding: 0px;
                        }
                        #header {
                                /*background-color: white;*/
                                background-color: #2B3856; /* #E3E4FA; Lavender */
                                margin-bottom: 5px;
                                height: 100px;
                        }
                        #header h1 {
                                color: #B93B8F; /* Plum */
                                line-height: 100px;
                                text-align: center;
                                font-size: 45px;
                        }
                        #description {
                                color: #7D1B7E /* Dark Orchid */
                        }
                        a {
                                text-decoration: underline;
                                color: #153E7E;
                        }
                        a:hover {
                                text-decoration: none;
                        }
                        div#posts {
                                padding: 0px;
                                font-size: 1.2em;
                                margin: 0px;
                        }
                        div#posts div.post {
                                padding: 5px;
                                margin: 0px 5px 15px 5px;
                        }
                        p.tags, p.published {
                                font-size: 1em;
                        }
                        .shadowbox {
                                background: repeat 0 0 url('http://www.jawsalgorhythmics.com/images/darkness-100x100-10pct.png');
                        }
                        .justifycenter { text-align: center; }
                        .floatright { float:right; }
                        .floatleft { float: left; }
                        .clearright { clear: right; }
                        .clearleft { clear:left; }
                        .clearboth { clear: both; }
                        .halfsidebarwidth { width: 82px; }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="container">
                        <div id="header">
                                <h1>Odds 'n Ends</h1>
                        </div> <!-- header -->

                        <div id="sidebar">
                                <div class="shadowbox">
                                        <br /><p class="justifycenter"><img width="64" height="64" src="{PortraitURL-64}" /></p>

                                        <div class="floatleft halfsidebarwidth"><a href="/archive" class="archive">Archives</a></div>
                                        <div class="floatleft halfsidebarwidth"><a href="{RSS}" class="rss">RSS</a></div>
                                        <div class="clearboth"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div> <!-- sidebar -->

                        <div id="content">
                                <div id="posts">

                                                <div class="post shadowbox">
                                                                <span class="quote">
                                                                        "It does not matter how slow you go so long as you do not stop."

                                                                        <div class="source">Wisdom of <a href="#" title="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confucius">Confucius</a></div>
                                                                </span>
                                                        <p class="tags">Tags: #<a href="#" title="http://demo.tumblr.com/tagged/wisdom">wisdom</a>&nbsp; </p>

                                                        <p class="published">Posted: Nov 08, 2006 at 2:27 pm
                                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" title="http://demo.tumblr.com/post/236/it-does-not-matter-how-slow-you-go-so-long-as-you">Permalink</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" title="http://tumblr.com/xr06k">Short URL</a></p>
                                                </div>

                                </div> <!-- posts -->
                        </div> <!-- content -->

                        <div class="clearboth"></div>

                        <div id="footer" style="text-align: justify;">
                                <h1>The footer</h1>
                        </div>
                </div> <!-- container -->
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use this instead of posting up a whole list of HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/JYfqL/.

Comment: That seems like a pointless and possibly wrong "technique" to me. Statements such as "By setting the body font-size to 62.5%, that will set your font size to 10 pixels" are wrong and I can't see how it make web design any easier or different. It just leads to problems such you are having.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `<p class="tags">` and `<p class="published">` elements are inside the `container` div, which has a font size of `1.4em`, and also inside in the `posts` div, which has a font size of `1.2em`. I think that setting the font size of the paragraphs to `1em` doesn't really do anything, as the `em` unit is cumulative. So if your "root" font size is 62.5%, it's going to be increased 40% for the first div, and increased another 20% for the second div. Your two paragraphs will also have this font size, as they aren't increasing or decreasing the size.

Basically, if you want the "tags" and "published" paragraphs to have smaller text, give them a size of less than one, e.g. `0.9em`. This will give them a size 10% less than other elements in the same parent div.

Comment: You are right, of course!!!!

That was really stupid of me—the em size is relative to the ancestor(s)—all of them!!! So of course the effect is cumulative.


Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Graham was right, I set;

```
p.tags, p.published {
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

And that changed the font size. [Updated Jsfiddle her](http://jsfiddle.net/JYfqL/5/)e.

The EM is calculated from the base size of the body font. [Look here](http://www.clagnut.com/blog/348/) for an explanation on how this works :)